# Prolog methods with certain conditions

Tags: recursion, prolog

I am trying to write a function where it gets new values on each `recursion` call and if it fails, then `increase` the the numbers and try it again until the number has reached `6` or `1`.

The important part here is that it should go to the second part only if it has succeeded once and increase or lower the number. And if it has succeeded once and increased/lowered it should check whether or not the function `try_to_do_math` works with the new number and if it doesn't then increase or lower the number again until the number reaches `6` or `1` unless it succeeds before the number hits `6` or `1`.

Also it should check whether it should `add` or `substract` by checking th value of `higer_or_lower`.

```
?- iterate_over(1, 1, Z, X).

iterate_over(X,Y,Z,higher_or_lower):-
    try_to_do_math(X,Y,X1,Y1,high_low),
    iterate_over(X1, Y1,1,high_low).
iterate_over(X,Y,Z,higher_or_lower):-
    higher_or_lower = 1, %Go higher
    Z = 1,
    X1 is X+1, X=<6,
    Y1 is Y+1, Y=<6,
    iterate_over(X1, Y1, 0,higher_or_lower).
iterate_over(X,Y,Z,higher_or_lower):-
    higher_or_lower = 2, %Go lower
    Z = 1,
    X1 is X-1, 1=< X,
    Y1 is Y-1, 1=< Y,
    iterate_over(X1, Y1, 0,higher_or_lower).
```

I am using variable `Z` to check if it succeeded before or not. If it is `1`, that means it has succeeded and if it is `_` empty then it has not.

With this code it always fails on `Z=1` because it does not have the value `1` when it reaches there to check it.

If `try_to_do_math` does not succeed on the first try then nothing should happen and `false` is returned.

If `try_to_do_math` succeeds the first time then it gives back new `X1 and Y1 and higer/lower`. And then I tried to pass on the variable `Z` as the state variable that is changed to 1 just on calling it again here `iterate_over(X1, Y1,1,high_low).`.

**EDIT**

I will try to do an example that would succeed.
Lets say the correct one is X = 5 and Y = 5.

First `?- iterate_over(1, 1, Z, X).` is called. 
Then it goes to `try_to_do_math(1, 1, X, Y, Z)` and gives back `try_to_do_math(1, 1, 3, 3, 0)`. 
Then it should try it again by calling `?- iterate_over(3, 3, 1, 0).`. Now it tries to call the `try_to_do_math(3,3,X1,Y1,higher_or_lower),` and it fails.

Now it should go to the lower `iterate_over` methods with values `iterate_over(3, 3, 1, 0)`, but this is where it does not work as I want it to. The method is called with numbers `iterate_over(3, 3, _, 0)` and since `1 != _` it all fails.

I am not sure if this is helpful, but I tried to explain it the way I see it.

Also if it succeedes then I do not care about the response as the `try_to_do_math` will only be changing things.

Comment: Can you show us some examples of the different transitions instead of the word description; that is hard to understand. Also need to see what the original query is, I have no idea what a query would be for this. I suspect this is a state transition problem and seeing the examples can help confirm it.

Comment: @GuyCoder Tried my best to explain it. If it is still messy, I can try to explain it again in another way.

Comment: We need the predicate `try_to_do_math`

Comment: Well there are actually many `predicates` attatched to it and they are way too long. But basically it checks wheter it is possible to find the solution with the given numbers or not and fails or succeeds. The main "point" of my question is how should I know that if the `try_to_do_math` has already failed once then and only then can I start calling other methods.

Comment: How should I know that if the `try_to_do_math` has already failed once? You need to pass a state variable around that holds the answer to this question. I am still learning what is going on in your code so I don't know if you have a variable for this yet.

Comment: The `try_to_do_math` returns new `X1, Y1 and higer_lower` and if it can't then it fails. I tried to pass on the state variable that it has already succeded once with `Z`. By changing it to 1 if `try_to_do_math` succeeded on the first try.

Comment: Of interest: `_` [Anonymous variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog_syntax_and_semantics#Anonymous_Variables)

Comment: Well this is what the `Prolog` calls it, but I do not want it to call it with `_` I want it to be assigned to int 1. I am sorry, it seems I am not capable of explaining it more.

Comment: I think I see your problem from reading your description. An anonymous variable `_` has special meaning in Prolog and comparing against it like you do `1 != _` is NOT going to work like you expect. You need to use a real variable there, e.g. `1 != A` and the variable needs to be bound to a value.

Comment: `Well this is what the Prolog calls it, but I do not want it to call it with _ I want it to be assigned to int 1.`  I don't understand what you are trying to say with that statement.

Comment: If this is homework, can you please post the entire problem, or a link if it is online. I get that you have a specific problem and that it is not working, but I don't see where the anonymous variable is coming from.

Comment: So the first time `iterate_over(X,Y,Z,higher_or_lower)` is called, it has no value `Z`. Then on the first try, I give it value 1. By calling the method again recursively with `iterate_over(X1, Y1,1,high_low).`. Now it tries to do the `try_to_do_math` but fails so it proceeds with the `iterate_over` that is in the lower block, that begins with this... `iterate_over(X,Y,Z,higher_or_lower):-
    higher_or_lower = 1..`. But when it calls this, the `Z` has no value, but I think it should have the value `1`. If I could give it value `1` then I could see if the method above succeded once already.

Comment: Each time you use `_` it is a completely new variable. There is no relationship between the `_` in the head and the `_` you are comparing to in the body, they are as different as quarks and kittens. This is a fact of life with Prolog, choose another variable name.

Comment: Also, `high_low` and `higher_or_lower` are _atoms_, not variables, so you cannot assign values to them or compare them with other values. Think of them as essentially strings. You *must* capitalize variable names in Prolog.